# Split string Apex

Tags: apex, string

Need to split a string by first occurence of specific character like `'-'` in `'this-is-test-data'`. so what i want is when i do split it will return 'this' in zero index and rest in first index.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `String.split(regExp, limit)` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split_2):

Documentation says

> Returns a list that contains each substring of the String that is
>   terminated by either the regular expression regExp or the end of the
>   String.

Example:

```
String str = 'this-is-test-data';
List<String> res = str.split('-', 2);
System.debug(res);
```

Result:

> 15:16:58:001 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|(this, is-test-data)

Answer (score 16):

One option is to use the `substringBefore` and `substringAfter` methods.

```
String delimiter = '-';
String input = 'this-is-test-data';
String firstSplit = input.substringBefore(delimiter); // 'this'
String lastSplits = input.substringAfter(delimiter);  // 'is-test-data'
```